# Magento 2: how to get logo full file path?

Tags: magento2, logo

In Magento 2, I can retrieve the logo image url by using this:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo $_logo){
  $logUrl = $_logo->getLogoSrc();
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve logo full directory image path ?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Create a module with the required files.  **`Dolphin_HelloWorld`**

**Step 2:** Create block **`app/code/Dolphin/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php`**

You will use a block class of the module Dolphin_HelloWorld, then possibly inject the object of Logo class in the constructor of the module’s block class.

```
<?php
namespace Dolphin\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_logo;    
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo $logo,
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_logo = $logo;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    /**
     * Get logo image URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLogoSrc()
    {    
        return $this->_logo->getLogoSrc();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get logo text
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLogoAlt()
    {    
        return $this->_logo->getLogoAlt();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get logo width
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getLogoWidth()
    {    
        return $this->_logo->getLogoWidth();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get logo height
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getLogoHeight()
    {    
        return $this->_logo->getLogoHeight();
    }    
}
?>
```

**Step 2:** Get Logo data in template (.phtml) file

Add the below function in your template (.phtml) file

```
echo $block->getLogoSrc() . '<br />';
echo $block->getLogoAlt() . '<br />';
echo $block->getLogoWidth() . '<br />';
echo $block->getLogoHeight() . '<br />';
```

Thanks,

Comment: At least add reference from where you took the code!

Comment: ok @pawan.Thanks